# How to calculate $\partial_j ( \sqrt{\gamma} \partial_j u)$?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

How to calculate $\partial_j ( \sqrt{\gamma} \partial_j u)$?

Where $\gamma \in C^2(\bar{\Omega})$ and $u \in H^1(\Omega)$.

I'm confused by how many times I need to use the chain rule and how many times the product rule.

Comment: You should know better by now not to post problem statement questions expecting users here to do your work for you.

Comment: @amWhy But I'm sometimes confused about what rule to use on which "abstraction level". Like which is the top-most expression of an expression. Or what kind of precedence rules there might be.

Answer (score 1):

Product rule once, and chain rule once:
$$
\partial_j ( \sqrt{\gamma} \partial_j u)
= \partial_j ( \sqrt{\gamma} ) \, \partial_j u + \sqrt{\gamma} \, \partial_j \partial_j u
= \frac{\partial_j\gamma}{2\sqrt{\gamma}} \, \partial_j u + \sqrt{\gamma} \, \partial_j \partial_j u
$$